# Get index shard count

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I need to get the number of primary shards for a particular index, in C#, using Nest (or Elastic.Net, doesn't matter). Which API call should I use?

1. IndicesShardStores
2. CatShards
3. GetIndexSettings

or something else?

Is this right and the best-performing way?

```
var settings = client.GetIndexSettings(i => i.Index(sourceIndexName));
settings.Indices[sourceIndexName].Settings.NumberOfShards
```

Comment: Try `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/shards?pretty'
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to count the number of primary shards of a given index, then `GetIndexSettings()` is the best option. Other options you listed return way more information than you need.